# Am I correct or not

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

Question asks to express this proposition using predicates connectives and quantifiers:

*When there is less than 30 megabytes free on the hard drive , a warning message is sent to all users*

**My solution:**

H(m):less than m megabyte free on the hard disk drive

W(x): a warning message is sent to user x

**H(30) → ∀x W(x)**

Is this solution right?

Comment: Why use predicate logic that way ? Maybe only $\text {Hard-driveFull} \to \text {Warning}$.

Comment: Okay. Actually I am following the discrete book written by Kenneth Rosen for self study. In that book he used letters for predicates. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Okay; you have to mimick **EXAMPLE 25** (page 50): Let H(m, y) be “Space free on hard drive m is less than y megabytes”; then $H(m,30)$. And $W(x)$ as above. Then maybe : $\exists x H(x,30) \to \forall y Q(y)$.

Comment: Very useful : [Solution Manual](https://www.slader.com/textbook/9780073383095-discrete-mathematics-with-applications-7th-edition/).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I also use sladder most of the time. But sometimes I need real help.